# proper threading in python

Tags: python, multithreading, mq

I am writing a home automation helpers - they are basically small daemon-like python applications. They can run each as a separate process but since there will be made I decided that I will put up a small dispatcher that will spawn each of the daemons in their own threads and be able to act shall a thread die in the future.

This is what it looks like (working with two classes):

```
from daemons import mosquitto_daemon, gtalk_daemon
from threading import Thread

print('Starting daemons')
mq_client = mosquitto_daemon.Client()
gt_client = gtalk_daemon.Client()

print('Starting MQ')
mq = Thread(target=mq_client.run)
mq.start()

print('Starting GT')
gt = Thread(target=gt_client.run)
gt.start()

while mq.isAlive() and gt.isAlive():
    pass
print('something died')
```

The problem is that MQ daemon (moquitto) will work fine shall I run it directly:

```
mq_client = mosquitto_daemon.Client()
mq_client.run()
```

It will start and hang in there listening to all the messages that hit relevant topics - exactly what I'm looking for.

However, run within the dispatcher makes it act weirdly - it will receive a single message and then stop acting yet the thread is reported to be alive. Given it works fine without the threading woodoo I'm assuming I'm doing something wrong in the dispatcher.

I'm quoting the MQ client code just in case:

```
import mosquitto
import config
import sys
import logging


class Client():
    mc = None

    def __init__(self):
        logging.basicConfig(format=u'%(filename)s:%(lineno)d %(levelname)-8s [%(asctime)s]  %(message)s', level=logging.DEBUG)
        logging.debug('Class initialization...')
        if not Client.mc:
            logging.info('Creating an instance of MQ client...')
            try:
                Client.mc = mosquitto.Mosquitto(config.DEVICE_NAME)
                Client.mc.connect(host=config.MQ_BROKER_ADDRESS)
                logging.debug('Successfully created MQ client...')
                logging.debug('Subscribing to topics...')
                for topic in config.MQ_TOPICS:
                    result, some_number = Client.mc.subscribe(topic, 0)
                    if result == 0:
                        logging.debug('Subscription to topic "%s" successful' % topic)
                    else:
                        logging.error('Failed to subscribe to topic "%s": %s' % (topic, result))
                logging.debug('Settings up callbacks...')
                self.mc.on_message = self.on_message
                logging.info('Finished initialization')
            except Exception as e:
                logging.critical('Failed to complete creating MQ client: %s' % e.message)
                self.mc = None
        else:
            logging.critical('Instance of MQ Client exists - passing...')
            sys.exit(status=1)

    def run(self):
        self.mc.loop_forever()

    def on_message(self, mosq, obj, msg):
        print('meesage!!111')
        logging.info('Message received on topic %s: %s' % (msg.topic, msg.payload))
```

Comment: Also, making `mc` a class attribute rather than an instance attribute might cause other issues if you spawn more than one instance per process (`Client.mc` vs. `self.mc`, and `mc = None` instead of just setting `self.mc` in the `__init__` stage,) depending on how mosquito client behaves with multiple instances.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing `Thread` another class instance's `run` method... It doesn't really know what to do with it.

`threading.Thread` can be used in two general ways: spawn a Thread wrapped independent function, or as a base class for a class with a `run` method.
In your case it appears like baseclass is the way to go, since your `Client` class has a `run` method.

Replace the following in your `MQ` class and it should work:

```
from threading import Thread

class Client(Thread):
    mc = None

    def __init__(self):
        Thread.__init__(self) # initialize the Thread instance
        ...
    ...

    def stop(self):
        # some sort of command to stop mc
        self.mc.stop() # not sure what the actual command is, if one exists at all...
```

Then when calling it, do it without `Thread`:

```
mq_client = mosquitto_daemon.Client()
mq_client.start() 

print 'Print this line to be sure we get here after starting the thread loop...'
```

Comment: it didn't really help, I'm trying to figure why.

Comment: I can't really test this code without your full runtime code (or a standalone stripped down version of it.) You may also have to implement a Stop method that propagates to the mosquitto client, and likewise with the gtalk daemon. I edited my answer to add the stop method.

Comment: I've found a couple of typos in my code and converted everything to be instance variables but it hasn't helped. Google Talk daemon uses the same Mosquitto class as the Mosquitto subscriber daemons and I guess this is causing some sort of confusion. I eventually gave up playing with that and converted everything to use RabbitMQ and it works great :)

Answer (score 1):

Several things to consider:

1. zeromq hates being initialized in 1 thread and run in another. You can rewrite Client() to be a Thread as suggested, or write your own function that will create a Client and run that function in a thread.
2. Client() has a class level variable mc. I assume that mosquitto_daemon and gtalk_daemon both use the same Client and so they are in contention for which Client.mc wins.
3. "while mq.isAlive() and gt.isAlive(): pass" will eat an entire processor because it just keeps polling over and over without sleep. Considering that python is only quasi-threaded (the Global Interpreter Lock (GIL) allows only 1 thread to run at a single time), this will stall out your "daemons".
4. Also considering the GIL, the orignal daemon implementation is likely to perform better.